# funcion para no agregar más filas a una tabla

Tags: javascript

Desde un formulario estoy agregando datos a una tabla, cuando le digo que haga `focus` lo hace, pero necesito que no siga agregando filas en la tabla ¿Alguna idea?

```
 function newRowTable()
    {                           
        if (NOMBRE == "") {
            document.getElementById("NOMBRE").focus();
        } else{
            if (FALTAS == "") {
                document.getElementById("FALTAS").focus();
            }else{
                if (CONDUCTA == "") {
                    document.getElementById("CONDUCTA").focus();
                }else{
                    if (NOTA == "") {
                        document.getElementById("NOTA").focus();
                    } else {
                        cell1.innerHTML = '<p name="materia_f[]" class="non-margin">'+MATERIA+'</p>';
                         cell2.innerHTML = '<p name="alumno_p[]" class="non-margin">'+NOMBRE+'</p>';
                         cell3.innerHTML = '<p name="faltas_p[]" class="non-margin">'+FALTAS+'</p>';
                           cell4.innerHTML = '<p name="conducta_p[]" class="non-margin">'+CONDUCTA+'</p>';
                             cell5.innerHTML = '<p name="nota_p[]" class="non-margin">'+NOTA+'</p>';
                              cell6.innerHTML = '<span class="icon-eliminar"></span><span class="icon-editar"></span>';
```

Comment: Por favor añade el codigo completo de la funcion `newRowTable`

Comment: Por favor explica un poco mejor la necesidad y añade más codigo, indícanos cuando se debe y cuando no agregar una nueva fila, aparte te recomiendo analizar si es posible cambiar tantos else if con un switch.